# What are the basics of Photography?

Tags: digital, learning, photography-basics

I am new to this site and extremely interested in photography.  I want to know what are the basics one should know while capturing a picture, and what are the prerequisites required to learn?

Comment: Here are some searches of the site to get you started.  If you have specific questions, please ask.

[tag:beginner](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning?sort=votes&pagesize=50)

[tag:learning](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginnersort=votes&pagesize=50)

Comment: This is a very broad question.  I'd suggest reading the above questions and answers, and then if you still have questions, ask simple, focused questions.  Are you wanting to know what resources (books, blogs, videos) you should check out, or asking us what we think the basics are to know?  Either way, still a very general question, so would be hard to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was a very broad. I will try my best to give a relevant answer. Try
http://photography.about.com, a very informative site. Also try reading the digital photography book by Scott Kelby and also try The Photographer's Eye by Michael Freeman, both are excellent books. There are many other sites in internet relating to photography giving you excellent information, and good luck with your photography.